# downloading in pdf is not working correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code for downloading a PDF document:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Contacts.pdf";

Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
datalist1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);

frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";

frm.Controls.Add(datalist1);
frm.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

It is working in Excel. While downloading in PDF it is showing this error:

> (Adobe reader could not open 'fileName.pdf' because it is either not a
>   supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example:
>   it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded))

Comment: I think what you generated is not a valid pdf file

Answer (score 0):

From a DB via a pass-through ASPX form:

```
try
{
    string selectQuery = 
        "SELECT Contact FROM dbo.Contacts WHERE dbo.Contacts.ContactID=" 
            + contactID.ToString();

    conn = new SqlConnection(CONN);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);

    conn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    dr.Read();
    context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", 
        "attachment; filename=Contacts.pdf");
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Display friendly message
    // Log and report error
}
finally
{
    dr.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```